# Обработка параметров YML файла

Tags: php, xml, yml

Обработал yml файл.
Вот фрагмент кода:

```
<offer id="33580859" available="true">
<url>
https://tablet4u.ru/products/blackview-bv9000-pro-grey
</url>
<price>18990</price>
<oldprice>19600</oldprice>
<currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
<categoryId>611152</categoryId>
<picture>
https://i.siteapi.org/TrmCwp1zAgRK6WsNtLqOmjBwSbg=/fit-in/1024x768/1f7cfbafce24d0e.ru.s.siteapi.org/img/szsy2h62oxwgcko8k4c8gcgccogwgk
</picture>
<name>BlackView BV9000 Pro grey</name>
<description>
Blackview BV9000 Pro – первый в мире ударопрочный и водостойкий смартфон IP68 с широкоформатным экраном 18:9 и функцией разблокировки по лицу! В отличие от BV9000 оснащается экраном Full HD+ (против HD+), оперативной памятью 6 ГБ (против 4 ГБ) и флеш-памятью 128 ГБ (против 64 ГБ).
</description>
<sales_notes>Оплата наличными, картой, кредит, юр. лица</sales_notes>
<vendor>Blackview</vendor>
<param name="Сенсорный экран"> есть </param>
<param name="Bluetooth"> есть </param>
<param name="GPS"> есть </param>
<param name="ГЛОНАСС"> есть </param>
<param name="Wi-Fi"> есть </param>
<param name="Слот для карты памяти"> есть </param>
<param name="3G"> есть </param>
<param name="4G LTE"> есть </param>
<param name="GPS/ГЛОНАСС"> есть </param>
<param name="Цвет">Gray</param>
</offer>
```

для тега `<param>` и `<offer>` создал две таблицы где в таблице param в поле product_id лежит id каждого offer т.е. они связаны по этим двум полям. Далее вывожу содержимое таблицы param в виде чекбоксов, чтобы при поиске товара т.е. offer можно было выбрать определенные параметры,проблема в том что при выводе всех данных из таблицы param имена повторяются т.е. допустим 4G может попадаться несколько раз.Как же тогда парсить такие параметры, создавать для каждого параметра свою таблицу?